# Printing run time messages in postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Can we use `RAISE NOTICE` in postgres as equivalent of `RAISERROR` 'message to display' `WITH NOWAIT` in SQL Server, or is there a better way to print intermediate messages while postgres queries are running? Please suggest if there is better way to print run time messages in postgres.

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (col1) values (val1);
DO $$
begin
raise notice 'insert tbl1 done!';
end;
$$;
UPDATE tbl2 set col2='val2' where ...;
DO $$
begin
raise notice 'update tbl2 done!';
end;
$$;
```

I apologize if this code is too bad to comment, pls do suggest a better way to do it, Thanks

Answer (score 71):

Yes, you can use `RAISE NOTICE` like below. It's correct the way you are doing.

```
RAISE NOTICE 'i want to print % and %', var1,var2;
```

See here for more information https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

EDIT:

```
begin
INSERT INTO tbl1 (col1) values (val1);
raise notice 'insert tbl1 done!';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Rahul, Ok but i was hoping if we can simplify the syntax around RAISE NOTICE just like how we run INSERT and UPDATE is it possible?

Comment: Not sure what's your Q. Give an example? But yes it's. With `RAISE NOTICE` you give the msg you want to print (like the way you are already doing); those `%` are placeholders.

Comment: I was asking if we can simplify the syntax                         DO $$
begin
raise notice 'update tbl2 done!';
end;
$$;                                                                 can we write                                                        insert tbl1                                                    RAISE NOTICE 'message'                                           update tbl2

Comment: No it doesnt seem to work without DO $$ begin end $$, I dont know if I am wrong

Comment: That `DO$$` syntax you use when using `anonymous block`.If that's how it's working then probably you can's simplify it anymore; sorry.

Comment: `RAISE` is a PL/PgSQL statement, not an SQL statement. So you cannot use it in top-level SQL, only within procedures. You can always create a trivial procedure that you can call as `raise_notice('message')` though.

Comment: Where can I see these messages after the function has run?

Answer (score 12):

you can use very simple statement in function everywhere.

```
DO $$ begin raise notice '%',now(); end; $$;
```

function for reference:

```
create or replace function test() RETURNS bool AS '
begin
raise notice ''%'',now();
for i IN 0..50000000  loop
     end loop
     raise notice ''%'',now();
     return true;
end;
```

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

Answer (score 4):

You could also do normal selects without the `DO` block.

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl1 (col1) values (val1);

SELECT 'insert tbl1 done!' as msg;

UPDATE tbl2 set col2='val2' where ...;

SELECT 'update tbl2 done!' as msg;
```

The tradeoff is that it does add extra clutter to the output, like

```sh
UPDATE 1
      msg
-----------------
update tbl2 done!
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

RAISE NOTICE is part of PL/pgSQL so it's only legal in a function or an anonymous DO block. I guess you could make a function that raises the notice and call that.

Comment: Thanks for comment, yes function may be a better approach if we want to print many messages, but currently I am sticking to DO blcok