# printing message when condition is satisfied in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

How to print message as delivery in 1 hr or 1 day depending on the conditions I provide in PostgreSQL query to generate jasper reports?

[I tried to use these solutions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508516/printing-run-time-messages-in-postgres)

```
$do$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (orderinfo.delivery_time - orderinfo.created_at) > '01:00:00' THEN
   raise notice 'dlvry in 1 hr' as dlvry;

END IF;
END
$do$
```

I tried above solution and it is returning a column with no data. I have to check many conditions like this to estimate the delivery time of a product to create jasper reports. please help.

Comment: Why do you use EXISTS? remove that from your query and it should work fine

Comment: no i am getting syntax error near do.

Comment: CASE
    WHEN orderinfo.delivery_time - orderinfo.created_at > '01:00:00' THEN 
  'delivery in 1 hr'  
  END 
  AS dlvryy

Comment: I tried the above code and it works fine but i have to check 4 conditions. Using different cases creates multiple columns named dlvryy.. what can i do to check different conditions inside same case block???

Comment: i got it... CASE
    WHEN orderinfo.delivery_time - orderinfo.created_at < '01:00:00' THEN 
  'delivery 1 Hour or less'  
   WHEN orderinfo.delivery_time - orderinfo.created_at <  '03:00:00' THEN 
  'delivery in 1 - 3 Hours'  
  WHEN orderinfo.delivery_time - orderinfo.created_at <  '48:00:00' THEN 
  'delivery in 3+ hrs'
  WHEN orderinfo.delivery_time - orderinfo.created_at >  '48:00:00' THEN 
  '2 - 3 Day Shipping'
  
  end
  AS dlvryy